# ASP.NET 5 - Azure AD Authentication - Redirect Loop when run with DNX web command - secrets.json

Tags: azure, iis, asp.net-core, dnx, azure-active-directory

I created a new ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 app (work and school accounts authentication) and I am getting a redirect loop when going to any authenticated page such as http://localhost:5000/Account/Signin.  This happens if I publish the app and run web.cmd (DNX) in the command prompt.

What I do know is if I set the hosting environment to Development, the issue is resolved on my dev machine but copying the published app with the same "--ASPNET_ENV Development" setting to any other machine gets the redirect issue.

```
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --ASPNET_ENV Development"
  },
```

I can reproduce this consistently.  Turning off Authentication also resolves the issue but not helpful for me.  Publishing to Azure also works.

Firstly, I would like to know why setting the Hosting Environment to development fixes the redirect issue on my dev machine and secondly, I would like to know why it does not work on any other machine.  Hosing in IIS on another machine also gives the redirect loop issue but it works fine in IIS express on my dev machine.

This is easy to reproduce.  In VS 2015, create a new ASP.NET 5 web app, choose  (work and school accounts authentication) and publish choosing File System.  Go to the publish directory and run web.cmd.  If it shows Hosting Environment Production, you will likely get the issue.  Changing Environment to Development will fix the issue but copying the the published app to another machine will have the same redirect issue even if with the Hosting Environment set to Development.

**UPDATE:**
I now know that the settings for Azure AD authentication e.g. Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance are in the secrets.json file  %APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\\secrets.json .  I can read them with the command line user-secret list.  This secrets.json file is only loaded if the environment is set to Development which answers my first question:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }
```

The secrets.json file is also not part of the deployment package so that answers my second question of why it does not work when I copy the package to another machine.

I know need to work out how secrets.json is meant to be used in a production environment.

Startup.cs is here as requested:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TestAzureAD
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
                builder.AddUserSecrets();
            }
            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"];
                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"];
                options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            });

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What build of ASP.Net 5 are you using? If you create an [AllowAnonymous] tag on one of your IActionResult endpoints e.g. HomeController.Index, can you browse to that URL or is it just the Account/Signin endpoint that causes the redirect?

Comment: The ASP.Net build is 1.0.0-rc1-final. 
The controllers have the [Authorize] attribute which sends the user to the login.microsoftonline.com page to login since I am using Azure AD authentication. Putting [AllowAnonymous] on an action method stops the redirect to the login page for that action but that is not desired.  The problem is that when I am running the app on another machine, the app does not know to go the login.microsoftonline.com page to login and instead redirects to itself.

Comment: I know it's not desired, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't anything else going on. Can you edit your post and provide your Startup.cs file please?

Comment: I have added startup.cs and also new information about the authentication settings in secrets.json.  I am now trying to find how secrets.json is meant to be used in production.

Comment: I have now resolved this.  I needed to copy the settings from the secrets.json to appsettings.json (or appsettings.[environmentname].json as the secrests.json is only on my dev machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings for Azure AD authentication e.g. Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance are in the secrets.json file %APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\secrets.json.  This would also apply for other authentication types.

The secrets API can be used to manage the secrets. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-Secret-Configuration

```
dnu commands install Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager 
user-secret list
```

In development on the dev machine, the secrets.json file can be used but on other machines, which wont have the secrets.json file, the settings need to be  read from appsettings.json and appsettings.[environmentname].json.  Copying the secrets.json settings to appsettings.json resolves the issue as the azure authenication now knows where to go and no longer redirects to itself in a loop.

The startup code shows that the settings are read from appsettings.json and appsettings.[environmentname].json and also from secrets.json in Development environment.

```
   public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```